# Jackson: Deserialize instantiated subclass of interface set (yml)

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

Given the following yml:

```
---
  commands:
    dev: !foo.bar.Baz {}
```

And the following class

```
public class PluginFile {
    private Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<String, Command>();
    public Map<String, Command> getCommands() {
        return commands;
    }
    public void setCommands(Map<String, Command> commands) {
        this.commands = commands;
    }
```

And reading the file:

```
mapper.readValue(theFile, PluginFile.class);
```

Results in error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of foo.bar.command.Command, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: C:\theFile.yml; line: 3, column: 10] (through reference chain: foo.bar.PluginFile["commands"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["dev"])
```

Which seems to be saying that Jackson cannot determine the concrete instance of the Command to set on pluginFile.commands().  However, that type is defined and created by the yml file itself with the !foo.bar.DevCommand {} syntax.

I can get this working by using the following yaml:

```
---
  commands:
    dev: 
      type: foo.bar.Baz
```

And then annotating the map property:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
```

But I really want to use the yaml Java literal syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Base class `Command` would need to have `@JsonTypeInfo` to indicate it requires polymorphic handling; and if so, Jackson would know to look for Type Identifier that YAML content has. If `foo.bar.Baz` specifies a class (that is, package `foo.bar`, class `Baz`), type inclusion should be specified as "class name".

Or, alternatively, you can specify `@JsonTypeInfo` for the map property as well. Something like:

```
public class PluginFile {
  @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
  private Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<String, Command>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the map property level annotation makes sense - But how do you specify type inclusion as "class name"?  (foo.bar.Baz is a fully qualified classname)

Comment: `CLASS` requires fully-qualified classname. There is also `MINIMAL_CLASS`, if (and only if!) all types are in same package, in which case package name is derived from the base type. It is also possible to just use logical `NAME`, but with that it is necessary to ensure subtype linkage exists (via `@JsonSubTypes`, or by registering subtypes via `Module`).

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm missing something still.  Will simply using the CLASS style automatically use the concrete class of the collection elements?

Comment: @mtyson yes. For structured types (Maps, Collections, arrays), type info included is for values/elements, and not for container itself, unlike with POJOs.